# p5.js — "Error: [object Arguments]is not a valid color representation" only when working with WEBGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, p5.js

I'm trying to draw a field of stars (among other things) using p5.js.

I get this error when I create my canvas using WEBGL, but the error goes away when I don't use it. However, I need the canvas to use WEBGL for other aspects of the project. Clearly I'm missing something here.

```
var CANVAS_SIZE = 600;

var starfield;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(CANVAS_SIZE, CANVAS_SIZE, WEBGL);
  noStroke();
  buildStarfield();
  
  // noprotect
}

function buildStarfield() {
  
  starfield = createImage(CANVAS_SIZE,CANVAS_SIZE);
  starfield.loadPixels();
  
  var starThreshold = 205; //threshold to weed out "less bright" stars
  
  for (var i = 0; i < CANVAS_SIZE; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < CANVAS_SIZE; j++) {
      // generate a noise map on which to base the starfield
      var c = 255 * noise(0.1 * i, 0.1 * j, random(0,1));
          
          // if c > starThreshold the draw a star else draw empty space
          if (c>starThreshold) {
            starfield.set(i, j, color(255,255,255,1));         
          } else {
            starfield.set(i, j, color(0,0,0,10));
          }  
        }
    }
  
  starfield.updatePixels();
  
}

function draw() {
  background(starfield);  
}
```

Here's where I'm testing, if it matters:

https://editor.p5js.org/

Any idea as to why would this `createCanvas(CANVAS_SIZE, CANVAS_SIZE);` work, but not `createCanvas(CANVAS_SIZE, CANVAS_SIZE, WEBGL);` this?

How can I make it work using WEBGL?

Comment: You are passing invalid values to [`background()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background). - The misleading error-message is just a bug of p5js.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher! 

Is there any way to get this image set up in a way that it would work for this use case, with WEBGL? 

For some reason the values I'm passing work with `background()` when not using WEBGL, but the WEBGL version doesn't like them.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a temporary bug with `background()` and `WEBGL`.

While that gets fixed you can use:

```js
image(starfield,-starfield.width / 2, -starfield.height / 2);
```

instead of `background(starfield)` to get the same visual outcome using `WEBGL` (it will work as `image(startfield, 0, 0);` if you're not using `WEBGL`)

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I don't have the reputation to upvote it, but thank you for providing it.

I'm not quite able to get this to work. How would I go about setting this up as the background image using the image method you mentioned above?

Thank you.

Comment: Happy to hear the answer is helpful. In your sketch, in the `draw()` function delete this line:  `background(starfield)` and paste this line: `image(starfield,-starfield.width / 2, -starfield.height / 2);`. Does that make sense ?